# Core Dumped due to delting an array

Tags: c++, arrays, linux

I'm trying to make a copy constructor with low level arrays and I'm getting a core dumped error when using delete, can't find out a solution because I'm not able to use std::vector to make this.
Can you guys help me ?? =)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<initializer_list>
class Vector{
    size_t n;
    double* datos;
public:
    Vector(size_t n_,double);
    Vector(const std::initializer_list<double>&l);
    void show();
    ~Vector(){
        delete[] datos;
    }
    Vector(Vector&& other):n(other.n){
        delete [] datos;
        datos =other.datos;
        other.datos =nullptr;
    }
    Vector(const Vector& v);
    Vector operator = (const Vector& v);
};
/* --------------------------- METODOS DE LA CLASE -------------------------- */
Vector::Vector(const Vector&v){
    delete[]datos; //CORE DUMPED
    n=v.n;
    datos = new double[n];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        datos[i] = v.datos[i];
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    
}
Vector Vector::operator = (const Vector& v){
    delete [] datos;//CORE DUMPED
    n = v.n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        datos[i] = v.datos[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
Vector::Vector(const std::initializer_list<double>&l):n(l.size()),datos(new double[n]){
    size_t j= 0;
    for (auto i:l)
    {
        datos[j]=i;
        ++j;
    }
}

void Vector::show(){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<datos[i]<<", ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
Vector::Vector(size_t n_,double d=0):n(n_),datos(new double[n]){
    if (n < 1)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong size!");
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        datos[i] = d;
    }
}
int main(){
    Vector b={2,3,4,5,6},a(3);
    a=b;
    a.show();
}
```

Using POP OS 21.04 (just in case this can help).

Please don't be rough with me I'm a junior programmer trying to pass September's exams =(

Comment: `delete[]datos; //CORE DUMPED` -- Ask yourself -- Why are you calling `delete[]` here in the copy constructor?  Do you know what the purpose of a copy **constructor** is?  If it is to construct a new object, what is there to `delete[]`?  The pointer is uninitialized anyway, but logically, why did you believe you need to delete anything there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Vector::Vector(const Vector&v){
>     delete[]datos; //CORE DUMPED
> ```

You didn't initialise `datos`, so its value is indeterminate. When you delete an indeterminate pointer, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. "CORE DUMPED" is one possible behaviour that you may observe.

Comment: This solved my problem, didn't realise that datos is empty in that line, thx =)

Answer (score 1):

You are issuing unneeded calls to `delete [] datos` in your constructors (move and copy).

Since `datos` is uninitialized, calling `delete []` on an uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behavior -- in your case, your program crashes.

Since the objects are being **constructed**, there is no reason to issue a `delete []` on the pointer, since the object `this` is brand new.

Simply remove the call to `delete [] datos;` from the constructors.  Whether this is the only problem is another story, but it is an existing one.

---

In addition, your assignment operator:

```
Vector Vector::operator = (const Vector& v)
```

is also incorrect.  It fails to allocate new memory after the `delete []` call, thus the `for` loop that is written will write into unallocated memory.  Also, it should return a reference to the current `Vector` object, not a brand new `Vector` object.

The easiest way to implement the assignment operator is to use `std::swap`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Vector& Vector::operator = (Vector v)
{
    std::swap(v.datos, datos);
    std::swap(v.n, n);
    return *this;
}
```

This assumes you have a working, non-buggy copy constructor and destructor for `Vector`.  See the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for details on why this works.